# Swift - Error 'Expected ',' separator' and 'Expected expression in list of expressions'

Tags: ios, swift

```
let screenBounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds   
var initialOrigin: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 108   
let offset: CGFloat = 108   
var lastItem: ViewModel?   
var currentURIs = [NSURL]()

lazy var panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:
    #selector(PlayerController.handlePanGesture(_:)))   
lazy var tapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:
    #selector(PlayerController.handleTapGesture(_:)))
```

Getting Errors `'Expected ',' separator'` and `'Expected expression in list of expressions'` for the above code..It would be great..if somebody enlighten me...

Comment: Are you sure you pasted this code correctly? You cannot put multiple statements on the same line.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with just the code you have posted (as formatted above). There were multiple statements in the code you had initially posted, which might be causing the issue if thats how it was written in your project. If not, you might want to specify the line where you get the error

Comment: This code is for Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7.3): update Xcode if your version is older.

Comment: thanks Eric D, i'm on Yosemite & Xcode 7.2...will update and try this...

Comment: or you may  change the `action:
    #selector(PlayerController.handlePanGesture(_:))` to `action:"handlePanGesture:" and like this`

Comment: thanks Pyro...i would try this now and post results here. and thanks lostInTransit for editing my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update the Xcode to 7.3 The new #selector syntax will only work in Xcode 7.3 (or newer)