# Swift 2: Selector in UIPinchGestureRecognizer: How to access func from another class

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97jg_zxVivg) class on Swift and building apps.

At 43:30 in the video, the instructor teaches how to set up a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`, which takes in a function from another file in its Selector.
This is the code the instructor uses:

```
@IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView! {
        didSet {
            faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: faceView, action: #selector(FaceView.changeScale(_:))))
            updateUI()
        }
    }
```

I get 2 errors:

> Expected expression in list of expressions,

and:

> Expected ',' separator.

I have tried changing `#selector` to `Selector` with no luck.

the function `changeScale`:

```
func changeScale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
    {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .Changed, .Ended:
            scale *= recognizer.scale //scale is the displayed image scale
            recognizer.scale = 1.0
        default:
            break
        }
```

If I surround the `Selector` argument with quotes, the app crashes when I pinch, giving the following error:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: where have you declared `changeScale`? In your `FaceView` class or in the   view controller?

Comment: @pbodsk I have declared it in FaceView.

Comment: OK...I've just tried creating a small example and it works on my machine (which you probably doesn't want to hear :)). I tried looking around to see if others have the same problem and it seems that some have had problems with older versions of Xcode, so... which version of Xcode are you using? You need at least Xcode 7.3 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347570/swift-error-expected-separator-and-expected-expression-in-list-of-expre).

Comment: @pbodsk I'm running 7.2. 7.3 means updating the OS and my mac is old. Sucks.

Comment: OK, that explains why you're seeing compiler errors at least. Lemme just write an answer using the old `Selector` syntax then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the comments above, the Xcode version is 7.2 and the `#selector` syntax was introduced in Xcode 7.3 and therefore not available here. This just means that you should be able to use the "old" `Selector` syntax.

The difference is that you just give pass a strings to the `Selector` with the name of your function and then a `:` for each of the parameters your function requires. You require one parameter (the `recognizer`) so in your case the string looks like this:

```
"changeScale:"
```

So you'd use:

```
Selector("changeScale:")
```

And you end up with:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView! {
    didSet {
            faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: faceView, action: Selector("changeScale:")))
        }
    }
```

As you can see, this is error prone...one typo and kaboom! Which is why the new `#selector` syntax is a fine improvement...sorry...not trying to rub it in.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This removes the error from xcode. But it doesn't call the function changeScale

Answer (score 2):

I am running Xcode 8.1(8B62) and a iPhone 5 simulator on MacBook Air (Ver 100.11.6)

This is the code I used that works

```
faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target:faceView,

action:#selector(FaceView.changeScale(recognizer:))))
```

When you pinch the face, make sure click "Option + Left Click + Movement on your mousepad". I make the mistake of just pressing "Option + Movement on the mousepad" and it does not work.

Hope it helps.